# Modification of US-Internation keyboard layout

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout

I have such question: how can i modify [US-International keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#US-International)?
By default to get this symbols: <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>´</kbd><kbd>¨</kbd> i need to press it twice or with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>
With [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/276931/256705)  I edited  */usr/share/X11/symbols/us*

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "intl" {

name[Group1]= "English (US, UNIm95 edit international with dead keys)";

include "us(basic)"

//Here only edited lines left
// Was
key <TLDE> { [dead_grave, dead_tilde,         grave,       asciitilde ] };
//Now
key <TLDE> { [     grave, asciitilde,    dead_grave,      dead_tilde  ] };


// Was
key <AE06> { [    6, dead_circumflex,    onequarter,      asciicircum ] };
// Now
key <AE06> { [        6, asciicircum,    onequarter, dead_circumflex  ] };   

// Was 
key <AC11> { [dead_acute, dead_diaeresis, apostrophe,        quotedbl ] };
// Now
key <AC11> { [apostrophe,   quotedbl,    dead_acute,   dead_diaeresis ] };
```

But it still works with double pressing. In Unity keyboard chooser I still can't find my layout:
[image: Layouts chooser]

If i choose English US-International it shows only standard  Us-International without my edits.
Reboot also doesn't helped.

- OS Ubuntu 14.04

**UPD 07.09.2015**

Alter reading [this link from ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) i found that after layout editing i need to reload it with

```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
```

**But also doesn't helped.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution!
After editing

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symblos/us
```

I needed to edit files

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.xml
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
```

Add lines in both files under section

```
  <layoutList>
      <layout>
          <configItem>
              <name>us</name>
              <shortDescription>en</shortDescription>
              <description>English (US)</description>
              <languageList>
                  <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
              </languageList>
          </configItem>
          <variantList>
              <variant>
                  <configItem>
                      <name>uni-intl</name>
                      <description>English (US, UNIm-95 international with dead keys</description>
                  </configItem>
              </variant>
```

Here you can get my us, base.xml, evdev.xml

- [us](http://pastebin.com/HTM5ZvJS)
- [base.xml](http://pastebin.com/6YCk7Jhb)
- [evdev.xml](http://pastebin.com/St8ChDvu)