# Own keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668541/modification-of-us-internation-keyboard-layout) i have asked question, how to edit keyboard layouts and find working solution for `Ubuntus` `12.04` - `16.04`
But now i got problems with `Ubuntu 18.04`.
After latest updates there was reconfiguration or full replacement of package `xkb-data`.
So i needed to re-edit all configs for proper work of my modified keyboard layout.

My question is simple:
Does `xkb-data` has some `conf.d` directory where i can place my layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately not. And yes, `xkb-data` is updated once in a while.

One thing you can do to make it less inconvenient is to put your custom variant in a separate file instead of editing the `us` file. Then, when `xkb-data` gets updated, you only need to redo `evdev.xml`/`base.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I will try to write some script, to automate re-enabling of my keyboards. Than i will post my answer as solution.